# Creating table of items with hyperlink to detail page

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a php page in which a dynamic table shows data from mysql database on user query. What I want is, when user select a row from table or click first column of a row then he/she should redirected to details of that particular item in that row. How to create the detail page based on the clicked entry? Data for detail page can be fetched from mysql.

Comment: And what have you tried????

Comment: Show your efforts here

Comment: I don't know how to get the clicked value. Like if user have clicked Item 13, how do I know that Item 13 have been selected so I can provide detail page for that item.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this..

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Item ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $id ?></td>
<td><?php echo $name?></td>
<td><a href="details.php?Item_id=<?php echo $id ?>>View</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In the details.php page get the id using this code

```
$item_id = $_GET["Item_id"];
```

and the process the query using the item id , and display the details.